# separating data using fscanf() issue

Tags: c, file, while-loop, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to read a file(list of employees) and store their data dynamically in a 2D array
example of the data of one employee **87:Xavier:Hartman:4500.000000:C:13**

```
typedef struct{
    int num; //Number 
    char pnom[20];//First name
    char nom[20];// Last name
    float salr;//salary 
    char grad[3];//grade 
    char sup[3];//the number of their superior employee 
}EMP;
```

```
EMP** alloc(FILE* pfp)
{
    int nbr=0;
    EMP tmp;
    EMP** T=NULL;
    while(fscanf(pfp,"%d:%s:%s:%d:%s:%s",&tmp.num,tmp.pnom,tmp.nom,&tmp.salr,tmp.grad,tmp.sup)==6){
        nbr++;
        T=(EMP**)realloc(T,sizeof(EMP*)*nbr);
        T[nbr-1]=(EMP*)malloc(sizeof(EMP));
        copy(T[nbr-1 ],tmp);
    }
    return T;
}
```

so basically The problem here in this ling `while(fscanf(pfp,"%d:%s:%s:%d:%s:%s",&tmp.num,tmp.pnom,tmp.nom,&tmp.salr,tmp.grad,tmp.sup)==6)`
**fscanf** supposed to return 6 but it returns 2 (it reads the number to **tmp.num** and all the rest to **tmp.pnom**)

Comment: Using `"%s"` without a width is poor programming.

Comment: INstead of `%s`, use `%19[^:]` to read up to the next colon.

Answer (score 1):

`"%s"` saves all non-white-space characters including `':'`.  Code attempted to save `"Xavier:Hartman:4500.000000:C:13"` into `tmp.pnom`.  Code needs to scan non-`':'`.

Always use *widths* with `"%s"`, `"%[]"`.

`"%d"` does not match a `float *`

```
// fscanf(pfp,"%d:%s:%s:%d ...
fscanf(pfp,"%d:%19[^:]:%19[^:]:%f:%2[^:]:%2s
```

---

Cast not need in `ptr = *alloc()`

No special `copy()` needed.  Best to initialize `EMP tmp = { 0 };` to aid in debugging.

```
// copy(T[nbr-1 ],tmp);

T[nbr-1 ][0] = tmp;
// or
*(T[nbr-1 ]) = tmp;
```